# Traveling Salesman with Special Metric

Tags: complexity-theory, mathematical-optimization, traveling-salesman

Euclidean TSP is known to be NP-complete.

In my special metric, the distance between A and B is defined as:

- from A to B = `max(x coordinate of A , y coordinate of B)`;
- from B to A = `max(x coordinate of B , y coordinate of A)`.

Is this still NP-complete?

Comment: No, just an interesting problem.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The calculation of the cost function is not what makes the TSP NP-complete.

The difference between your formulation and the "standard" TSP is that the cost
differs depending on the direction you are traveling. That is cost(i,j) != cost(j,i).
Costs are usually represented as a matrix for easy look up and the symmetry lets you halve the size of the cost matrix. Your formulation requires the matrix to be completely filled in. The generation of the cost matrix is still only O(n^2).

For an exact answer you will still need to brute-force your answer (with the number of possibilities == the number of permutations of "cities" O(n!)) or use a fancy algorithm like a SAT solver.

Comment: Thanks! But, to prove its np-completeness, we need to reduce from another np-complete problem. I think "the cost differs depending on the direction" is not the only difference.

Comment: Assume you have an algorithm to solve your asymmetric TSP. First, observe that it is in NP. Clearly, it also solves any instance of Euclidean TSP. Since Euclidan TSP is NP-complete (and thus NP hard), the asymmetric TSP is NP-hard too. Thus, asymmetric TSP is NP-complete.

Comment: Do you have more information relative to use a SAT solver for the metric TSP?